# getCurrentState() returns only "INITIALIZED"

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I'm having doubt in following code snippets.

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleOwner,LifeCycleComponant {

    private static final String TAG =MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getLifecycle().addObserver(new MyObserver());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: ");
        getState();
    }

    @Override
    public void getState() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getState: "+getLifecycle().getCurrentState());
    }
}
```

MyObserver.Java

```
    public class MyObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
    private static String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private LifeCycleComponant lifeCycleComponant;
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    public void myOnCreate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "myOncreate: ");
        lifeCycleComponant=new MainActivity();
        lifeCycleComponant.getState();
    }
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    public void myOnDestroy(){
        Log.d(TAG, "myOnDestroy: ");
        lifeCycleComponant.getState();
        lifeCycleComponant=null;
    }
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    public void myOnResume(){
        Log.d(TAG, "myOnResume: ");
        lifeCycleComponant.getState();
    }
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    public void myOnPause(){
        Log.d(TAG, "myOnPause: ");
        lifeCycleComponant.getState();

    }
}
```

Whenever I'm calling lifeCycleComponant.getState() it only returns INITIALIZED.
But when I'm calling it from MainActivit.onPause() method it gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lifeCycleComponant=new MainActivity();`

will create a new Activity which will be in initialized state and won't have link to your `Activity` which is running in foreground.

You don't need to access current state in the Observer since it will be triggered based on appropriate `Lifecycle.Event`